# ServiceWorker unregister - how to fully clean up (event missing)

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

e.g. i have a ServiceWorker that will only log to the console that he is alive for every second.

service-worker.js:

```
setInterval(() => {
  console.log("ALIVE");
}, 1000);
```

Now in my application I do have an unregister button that will trigger `this.serviceWorkerRegistration.unregister()`.

The ServiceWorker will be marked as deleted (*in Devtools*) but is still up and running in Google Chrome. This means the logging continues... Even if I delete the whole application using  *Devtools -> Application -> Clear Storage*....

I was hoping to find an event like `this.addEventListener("install", function(e) ...` but according to the spec there is none.

**So how am I supposed to do the cleaning up stuff in my ServiceWorker??**

I had hope to solve the issue by storing the `setInterval` in an variable so the garbage collector might delete it - but **nope**.

Comment: btw: Firefox will delete the interval after unregister() and hard reload of the site. Chrome will delete the interval after you close the tab completely - reloading in the same tab will result in continuous execution of the `setInterval`.  But still I want to trigger a full delete / unregister from my javascript code that does not require the visitor to leave the page..

Comment: The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#navigator-service-worker-unregister) indicates: `It is important to note that the currently controlled service worker client's active worker's containing service worker registration is effective until all the service worker clients (including itself) using this service worker registration unload. That is, the unregister() method only affects subsequent navigations.` I could be wrong, but I interpret that to mean the SW cannot immediately delete itself, which explains the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Have you tried to all the cachese i nthe service worker and delete any caches that aren't defined i nthe cache whitelist? Check this https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers#cache_and_return_requests